# Is it possible to define the width/height of a Terminal window with this command: osascript -e \'tell application "Terminal" to do script

Tags: terminal

I am using this command to do some magic for my personal use:

```
osascript -e \'tell application "Terminal" to do script
```

Is it possible to precisely define the width and height of the popup Terminal window?

If not, is there anyway I can do it after it's opened? (Precisely adjust its size value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a Terminal window and position it on the screen where you want it and resize it to the size you want.

Then in Terminal, execute the following *command*:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to get bounds of front window'
```

It will return a four-item list of integers, e.g:

```
0, 22, 730, 531
```

Now move the Terminal window to a different position on the screen and resize it.

Then in Terminal, execute the following *command*, while substituting the actual list returned from the `get bounds` *command*, e.g:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set bounds of front window to {0, 22, 730, 531}'
```

You'll see that the window gets repositioned and resized to what it was when you ran the `get bounds` *command*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to resize any other Application in this way? (For example, a Safari window)

Comment: @Aw Qirui Guo, Yes, just substitute the applications name, e.g. `osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to set bounds of front window to {0, 22, 730, 531}'`