# Applescript to set terminal window to specific size

Tags: terminal, applescript, resolution

I found this question [Is it possible to define the width/height of a Terminal window with this command: osascript -e \'tell application "Terminal" to do script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266426/is-it-possible-to-define-the-width-height-of-a-terminal-window-with-this-command)

and tried setting my Terminal window resolution to 1920x1080 with

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 1920, 1080}'`

but the width of the window stretches over the entire screen and it's definitely not 1920x1080. My screen resolution is 2880x1800 (macbook pro 15" retina)

Comment: Probably characters, not pixels

Comment: based on all the links I could find it's supposed to be in pixels

Comment: Retina displays are normally scaled (or things get really small).  Try something smaller.

Comment: See what gets returned if you run this: `tell application id "com.apple.finder" to get bounds of desktop's window`.  That will give you the maximal bounds that can be contained within the visible portion of the screen.

Comment: I need to set my terminal window to exactly 1920x1080 size for screen recording.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. I was suggesting you run that code so you know how big your screen is. Then if you take that as a proportion of 2880x1800, you can easily calculate what 1920x1080 would be in "AppleScript pixels".

Answer (score 2):

Scaled-down values need to be given to `osascript`. You'll need to experiment as [CJK](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/266364/cjk) said.

In my case, I want a size that is the same proportions as HD (`1920x1080`), but maximize my screen width. I made my Terminal the full width and height of the screen (manually, not with the "full screen" button because I want to preserve the menu bar). Then ran:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to get bounds of front window'

=> 0, 23, 1440, 900
```

So, it looks like the menu bar is `23` pixels, and the width used by `osascript` is `1440`. `1440` width in an HD ratio is `1440x810`.

So, the command for me that results in a max width window that is HD ratio is:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set bounds of front window to {0, 23, 1440, 833}'
```

The `833` is `810 + 23` to account for the menu bar height.